# Xcode multiple storyboards with landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I am using the approach mentioned in http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-a-different-storyboard-depending-on-screen-size-in-ios/ to add code in Appdelegate.m to use different storyboards for different iphone sizes. However when I do this I am unable to specify that app orientation should be landscape - it keeps it both portrait and landscape.

As soon as I change anything in info.plist to fix the orientation then the appdelegate.m functions stops getting called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the article date, its 2013. You have a really better choise here. Use auto layouts for this approach. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) and a better one [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) or you can use size classes for an adaptive layout in iOS 8. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)